# What kind of exercises will help out in rest days?

Tags: weightlifting, workout, rest

I'm doing full body weight training 3 days a week like most people.

I'd like to do a 5-20 minute workout on my off days that can compliment my weight training without messing up with my muscle's rest-period.

Would appreciate if the suggestions are bodyweight exercises I can do when I've recently woke up. (Some physical activity also helps waking up from naps and sleep)

Answer (score 2):

Better to do stretching exercises or yoga to make body more flexible and good muscle growth. 
Do surya namaskram which is in yoga . And it related to body weight

Answer (score 1):

Definitely do some stretching. It TREMENDOUSLY helps with weightlifting. Also, any time of cardio will be good. Their are countless studies their that show that cardio can help with nutrition portioning. Also cardio just helps keep your heart fit

Answer (score 0):

After your wake up, your body would be in it's lowest potential to do something intense immediately. All you need to do is, make it prepared first. That being said, I'd say just brisk walking on rest days would help. Or jogging, but nor running. Rest days means you are giving your muscles a break. Walking would also help you after sleep or nap, to get your system ready for anything you are up to next.